# how to save changes to toggle button

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse

i want to make toggle button that can play background sound service. here is my code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Switch mySwitch;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

        public void playRain(View view) {
        // Is the toggle on?
        boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayRain.class);
            startService(objIntent);
        } else {
            Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayRain.class);
            stopService(objIntent);  
        }
    }

}
```

when i switch the toggle button to on, the sound play. but when i hit the home button and re open the app the toggle button go back to off. how to save changes to toggle button? so that the toggle button does not go back to off state by itself. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to save the state of the toggle button in SharedPreferences.
[This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) might help.

i have written a sample code. I hope it helps

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

private Switch mySwitch;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor edit;
final String SOUND_PREF_KEY = "background_sound";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = pref.edit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mySwitch.setChecked(pref.getBoolean(SOUND_PREF_KEY, false));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
        edit.putBoolean(SOUND_PREF_KEY, true);
    } else {
        edit.putBoolean(SOUND_PREF_KEY, false);
    }
    edit.commit();

}

public void playRain(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayRain.class);
        startService(objIntent);
    } else {
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayRain.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
    }
}

}
```